# How change the name of file that uploaded to server in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

I have a file uploading script like this

**HTML**

```
<input type = "file" name = "football" >
```

when uploading a file with name **messi.png**

**PHP**

```
print_r($_FILE['football']['name']);
```

output is **messi.png**

I want to change the file name **messi.png** to **messi_fan.png** in javascript
ie

```
print_r($_FILE['football']['name']);
```

gives **messi_fan.png**.
please give me a javascript solution. don't need php solution.

Comment: http://www.wangarific.com/rewrite-rename-filenames-using-javascript/

Comment: To my knowledge (and i found no sources telling otherwise), the filename is embedded in the request by the browser and cannot be directly specified. Try telling us what you why you need to change the filename and maybe someone can provide an alternative?

Comment: @DipeshParmar - What's WScript code. It wont' work in a regular browser.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should get the value of type file in JavaScript

```
var  url ='messi.png'; 
var name = url.replace(/^.*\/|\.[^.]*$/g, '')
```

and separate string add with extra string  with url name.likewise use the concat  string  as your image name.you can get value of image by $_post in php